# sql server index out of range error

Tags: java, sql-server, range

i have this error . The index 2 is out of range. on pst.setString(2, textField.getText();
how can i deal with it.

this is my code

```
try{
    String sql="update inventory set Name=?,Category=?,Brand=?,Price=?,ExDate=?,Tags=?,Quantity=?,Barcode=? where Id=?"; 
    pst.setString(2, textField.getText());
    pst.setString(3, textField_1.getText());
    pst.setString(4, textField_2.getText());
    pst.setString(5, textField_3.getText());
    pst.setString(6, textField_4.getText());
    pst.setString(7, textField_5.getText());
    pst.setString(8, textField_9.getText());
    pst.setString(9, textField_6.getText());
    pst.setString(1, textField_8.getText());
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updating Item Successful","Updated",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    new server().setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
} catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: for what its worth, I'd move pst=con.prepareStatement(sql); right after my String declaration (the line String sql = "") and then setter methods.

Comment: I don't believe all those columns are really `varchar` columns. Why do you use `setString()` on all of them then? You should be using the appropriate `setXXX()` method to pass the values (e.g. `setInt()` or `setDate()`) instead of letting the driver implicitly convert everything.

Comment: @Ashish i just solve my problem. the textField aren't on the right places. thanks for the help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you have a point. i'm changing my code right now. :)

Comment: @Rohan21 , if you found my answer helpful, please do not forget to vote up or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), Couple of things to notice here.

your sql contains **name** att index 1. So when you try to update this column you should use the same index. something like this:

```
pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
```

You are always invoking setString methods. Although it looks like some of the columns might be of type **int** or else. for example your 'id' column should be set with this:

```
pst.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(textField_8.getText()));    (notice that I have changed the index as well.)
```

And as I mentioned in my comment earlier, you should move your `pst=con.prepareStatement(sql)` to the top. (right after your string declaration.)

Comment: i have tried it and now i have the error The conversion of the nvarchar value '3565547456644' overflowed an int column.

Comment: so the idea is to use specific setter methods which corresponds to the data type of a column. you can check out this link to see what could be the best fit in your case. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 1):

A prepared statement should be created before being used to set the variables. As the commenter said you need to move the prepared statement creation **before** setting variables to it.

Refactor your code like this:

```
try{
    String sql="update inventory set Name=?,Category=?,Brand=?,Price=?,ExDate=?,Tags=?,Quantity=?,Barcode=? where Id=?"; 
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(2, textField.getText());
    pst.setString(3, textField_1.getText());
    pst.setString(4, textField_2.getText());
    pst.setString(5, textField_3.getText());
    pst.setString(6, textField_4.getText());
    pst.setString(7, textField_5.getText());
    pst.setString(8, textField_9.getText());
    pst.setString(9, textField_6.getText());
    pst.setString(1, textField_8.getText());

    pst.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updating Item Successful","Updated",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    new server().setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
} 
catch(Exception e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
finally 
{
    pst.close();
}
```